# Tab control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I'm doing my project and I design including many tab controls in VB.NET.

Example:

I have 3 tab pages like tab1,tab2,tab3. And I have menu bar to open tab1,tab2,tab3.

How can you use code to open each tab page?

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Is this WinForms or WebForms?

Comment: Is this Homework or Legitimate?

Comment: @Charlie, should it really matter? He/she still has to learn how to do it regardless.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to just handle the OnClick event of your menu buttons and just doing:

```
Me.MyTabControl.SelectedTab = index;
// 0 = Tab1, 1 = Tab2, 2 = Tab3
```

Obviously you would replace index with whichever tab you wish to open.

Incase you don't know how to handle the OnClick event, just double click on the button's and the OnClick event is automatically generated for you. Then per button_onclick you just put in the above code, with the index you wish to open when that button is clicked.

Comment: You don't override the OnClick event. You handle it.

Comment: Yeah spose in technical terms you are right, updated accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

TabControl1.SelectTab(0) ' if you wanted to open the first tab in TabControl1

TabControl1.SelectTab(1) ' if you wanted to open the second tab in TabControl1

.............................................(2) ' .......................................................3rd......................

.............................................(3) ' .......................................................4th......................

etc.